# File Upload in WebView Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

I want to allow an upload button from my WebView Android Application. Since I'm not an android developer, I need your help to enable image uploader for Android WebView. This is my MainActivity file.

```
package com.hfzgk.hfzgk;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView myWeb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setPage();
    }

    private void setPage(){

        myWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myViewId);
        WebSettings myseeting = myWeb.getSettings();
        myseeting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWeb.loadUrl("http://www.hfzgk.tk/");
        myWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (myWeb.canGoBack())
            myWeb.goBack();
        else
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

try this as your mainactivity.java:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import java.io.*;
import android.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import android.annotation.*;
import java.util.*;
import android.app.*;
import android.provider.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.webkit.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static final int REQUEST_CODE_LOLIPOP = 1;
private final static int RESULT_CODE_ICE_CREAM = 2;
private WebView webView;
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
private String mCameraPhotoPath;
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;

private String url ="http://up.example.com";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);


webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wbvw);
setUpWebViewDefaults(webView);
webView.loadUrl(url);



   webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        private String TAG;
        // For Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"),
                                   RESULT_CODE_ICE_CREAM);

        }
        // For Android 3.0+
         public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                                   RESULT_CODE_ICE_CREAM);
        }
        //For Android 4.1
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"),
                                   RESULT_CODE_ICE_CREAM);

        }
        //For Android5.0+
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(
            WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
            FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                }
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                               Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                } else {
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }
            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");
            Intent[] intentArray;
            if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            } else {
                intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }
            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_CODE_LOLIPOP);

            return true;
        }
       });
      }
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
   // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
    imageFileName,  /* prefix */
    ".jpg",         /* suffix */
    storageDir      /* directory */
     );
   return imageFile;
    }
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void setUpWebViewDefaults(WebView webView) {
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
   // Enable Javascript
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    // Use WideViewport and Zoom out if there is no viewport defined
   settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
   settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
   // Enable pinch to zoom without the zoom buttons
   settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    // Hide the zoom controls for HONEYCOMB+
    settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
   }
   // Enable remote debugging via chrome://inspect
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
   }
   // We set the WebViewClient to ensure links are consumed by the WebView rather
   // than passed to a browser if it can
   webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }
   @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case RESULT_CODE_ICE_CREAM:
        Uri uri = null;
        if (data != null) {
            uri = data.getData();
        }
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(uri);
        mUploadMessage = null;
        break;
      case REQUEST_CODE_LOLIPOP:
        Uri[] results = null;
        // Check that the response is a good one
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data == null) {
                // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                }
            } else {
                String dataString = data.getDataString();
                if (dataString != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                }
            }
        }
        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
        mFilePathCallback = null;
        break;
      }
      }

      }
```

also add this in your activitymain.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">



<WebView
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


</WebView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and finally don't forget to give permission in your manifest.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.aashiq.multipleimg">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>

  </manifest>
```