# Android Studio SDK 30 (2021) webview how to make file input prompt user gallery, photo OR VIDEO and actually uploads

Tags: android-studio, file-upload, webview, android-camera

Android Studio / SDK 30 I need to upload into a input file in webview.

There is TONS of 6,7 to 8 years ago answers that don't work anymore :(

I have a working webview that can use .getUserMedia (webrtc), can use GPS, but is unable to upload in a regular `<input type="file" >`

This code does ask (when start the app) permissions for camera, storage, gps...

I want to trigger a prompt that ask the user take photo, take video or choose from gallery and that actually uploads it.

here my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.apptheway.wexview">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA2" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.webkit.PermissionRequest" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here MainActivity

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.PermissionRequest;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.util.Random;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        String[] permissions = {
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        };

        requestPermissions(permissions, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
            String permission = permissions[i];
            boolean isGranted = grantResults[i] >= 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        mWebView = new WebView(this);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        webSettings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

                String url = request.getUrl().toString();

                int opensInWexView = 1;

                // DOMAINS
//                if ( !url.contains("stubfee.com") && !url.contains("stubfee.com") && !url.contains("stubfeedevent.com") ) {
//                    opensInWexView = 0;
//                }

                // IF FILE
                if (    url.contains(".pdf") || url.contains(".mov") || url.contains(".mp") ||
                        url.contains(".hv") || url.contains(".aif") || url.contains(".wav") ||
                        url.contains(".xls") || url.contains(".doc") || url.contains(".txt")
                ) {
                    opensInWexView = 0;
                }

                // URL SCHEME
                if (    url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("sms:") ||
                        url.startsWith("mms:") || url.startsWith("mailto:") ||
                        url.startsWith("fax:")
                ) {
                    opensInWexView = 0;
                }

                switch (opensInWexView) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    default:
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                        break;
                }

                return true;

            }
        });

        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            // CAMERA
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                request.grant(request.getResources());
            }

            // GPS
            public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
            }

            // FILE INPUT

        });

        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.stubfee.com/account/" + (new Random().nextInt((1000000 - 1) + 1) + 1) + "/");

        this.setContentView(mWebView);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(final int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

In many answers they talk about adding code inside

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {}
```

But any answer from the web I try; it does work :(

in one of the answers, I get the gallery to open, but when select a file, nothing happens :(

is there a more recent approach ?

what I'm I missing ?

Tried those without success

[Upload an Image from camera or gallery in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725814/upload-an-image-from-camera-or-gallery-in-webview)

[Android Webview Upload Image from gallery or camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46899460/android-webview-upload-image-from-gallery-or-camera)

[Saving photos and videos using Android FileProvider to the gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43247674/saving-photos-and-videos-using-android-fileprovider-to-the-gallery)

[File Upload in WebView Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45603682/file-upload-in-webview-android-studio)

[How to Upload Files with WebView in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23249657/how-to-upload-files-with-webview-in-android-studio)

[How to make upload button work in android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442843/how-to-make-upload-button-work-in-android-app/15454070#15454070)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and was having problems with `WebChromeClient`, too, and I recently found the answer. `onShowFileChooser` is the key event. (I had trouble trying to pass mWebView as a param to a new class constructor, but it did work when I kept the definition inside `MainActivity`.)

Also, this technique avoids the now-deprecated `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult` functions.

**In Kotlin**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    supportActionBar!!.hide()
    val progressBarView = findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.webviewProgress)
    mWebview.settings.allowContentAccess = true
    mWebview.settings.allowFileAccess = true
    mWebview.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
    mWebview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    mWebview.webViewClient = AppWebViewClient(progressBarView)
    mWebview.webChromeClient = object:WebChromeClient() {
        override fun onShowFileChooser(mWebView:WebView,
                                       filePathCallback:ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>,
                                       fileChooserParams:FileChooserParams):Boolean {
            if (mUploadMessage != null) {
                mUploadMessage!!.onReceiveValue(null)
                mUploadMessage = null
            }
            mUploadMessage = filePathCallback
            val contentSelectionIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            contentSelectionIntent.type = "*/*"
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER)
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent)
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "File Chooser")
            try {
                getFileResultLauncher.launch(intent)
            } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                mUploadMessage = null
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Open File Chooser", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                return false
            }
            return true
        }
    }
    mWebview.loadUrl(getString(R.string.app_url))

}

val getFileResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
) {
    ar: ActivityResult ->
    val intent: Intent? = ar.data
    val result = if (intent == null || ar.resultCode != RESULT_OK) null else arrayOf(Uri.parse(intent.dataString))
    mUploadMessage!!.onReceiveValue(result);
    mUploadMessage = null;
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    _webview.goBack()
}
```

Comment: NOTE: this is tweaked from my own personal implementation, because you are declaring mWebView as a class field, whereas I declare it inside the `onCreate` function itself. `onShowFileChooser` doesn't reference it anyway, so it shouldn't be a problem, but if you are having trouble, you might look into that.

Comment: Cool, I'll test it soon. I'll get back with results of the test

Comment: how would it be in java?